# KCFinder - You don't have permission to access /admin/kcfinder/browse.php on this server. IPAGE WEBHOSTING

Tags: php, yii, kcfinder

I have a web application on a server and it works. When i moved to IPAGE webhosting the image upload doesnt work anymore.
If i click the "browes the server" it says : You don't have permission to access /admin/kcfinder/browse.php on this server.
The admin page is under the main page in /admin folder.
 Here is my code in the controller:

```
  $_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled'] = false;
  $_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadURL'] = Yii::app()->baseUrl."/../images/"; // URL for the uploads folder
  $_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadDir'] = Yii::app()->basePath."/../../images/"; // path to the uploads folder
```

I checked the urls and its good.

My .htacces file in kcfinder folder:

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_flag engine Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php6.c>
  php_flag engine Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_cgi.c>
  Options -ExecCGI
</IfModule>
RemoveHandler .cgi .pl .py .pyc .pyo .phtml .php .php4 .php3 .php5 .php6 .pcgi .pcgi3 .pcgi4 .pcgi5 .pchi6 .inc
RemoveType .cgi .pl .py .pyc .pyo .phtml .php .php4 .php3 .php5 .php6 .pcgi .pcgi3 .pcgi4 .pcgi5 .pchi6 .inc
SetHandler None
SetHandler default-handler
```

Comment: https://github.com/bramley/phplist-plugin-ckeditor/issues/5 `In the kcfinder directory there should be a .htaccess file that allows access to browse.php and other files.`

Comment: Ty. I put the .htaccess file in the question. What is the problem with this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solve the problem. Ipage has unique session_path. So you have to set the session path.
http://www.ipage.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=600

Comment: Hello, I am with ipage as well. Where do you put this code ?

Comment: Hello, put it in index.php and lets start the session there.